# Как в JavaScript получить дату из числа?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как в javascript (использую vue.js) преобразовать число в дату?

К примеру у меня есть такая переменная - **updated: 1485789600**.

Как сделать так, чтобы это число *преобразовалось в дату* такого плана - (**Monday, 30 January 2017, 15:20**)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript

Comment: начните с `new Date(1485789600)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как отметил @cauf

нужно  updated: 1485789600 помножить на 1000

```
  const date = new Date(1485789600*1000);
```

`new Date` Создаёт экземпляр объекта `Date`, представляющего собой момент времени. Объекты Date основываются на значении количества миллисекунд, прошедших с 1 января 1970 года в часовом поясе UTC.

Соответственно если у вас в секунда задана дата то нужно умножить на 1000 и получить в миллисекундах

Answer (score 0):

```
let timestamp = 1485789600;
let date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
let options = { weekday: 'long', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric', month: 'long' };
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options));
```

На выходе будет такая дата Monday, January 30, 2017 или с помощью функций Date ты можешь настроить нужный вам формат вывода.